# Get written statement from landlord for a mold that could happen because of his decision over phone?

Tags: germany, landlord

In my apartment I closed up the ventilation in my bathroom with baking paper. The reason is since it is summer
many insects like hornets, wasps and even centipedes started coming from that ventilation hole. Obviously 
I contacted my landlord. He told me to keep the hole closed, that no one before me had that problem and to keep my windows open when I showered so that there couldn't be a chance
of mold appearing. He told me this over phone. Now I don't know if I should get a written statement from him because if mold gets in there, I don't want to pay for anything.

Information: I am from Germany, my landlord is actually a really cool guy but kinda greedy. I never had any other problems. I just don't know if he is too lazy or what I should do now.

Comment: There should be some kind of screen or flap on the vent's exterior to prevent insects from coming in when the fan is not on. The landlord should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, all rental agreement will ask the tenant to keep the property in good condition, so it is the tenant responsibility to prevent mold growing inside the bathroom, or else you must fix it or pay for the repair.

Here are some tips to keep the bathroom dry

1. Use a dry towel to wipe out all the water droplet after taking the bath. This allows you to dry out the bathroom with less time. In addition, since most of the pipe-water in Germany is hard water, this will also reduce water stains accumulation.
2. Do the same to your bathroom sink. It is easier to deal with the towel than the water stains and mold.
3. Install insects or even pollen net to your bathroom window.
4. Taped insects net to the ventilation hole.
5. If you do step 1 and 2, open the Windows fully from 30mins is more effective to flush the humid air than leaving a crack in the windows for hours.

Comment: I thought in most rental agreements the landlord was also responsible to ensure the equipment and utilities built into the building works. It sounds like if the ventilator isnt stopping insects properly to the point it needs paper there is something badly wrong with it and it needs replacing.

Comment: @Vality Actually OP didn't mention whether it is a ventilation vent with a mechanical closing mechanism.